# Best practices for using app_offline with webdeploy

Tags: webdeploy, app-offline.htm

When I deploy my web site I need to:

- Take the site offline.
- run sql to update the database.
- update the web site.
- Put the site back online

I would like to script as much of this as possible without have to go the server and make manual changes.

I am currently using WebDeploy to push my website changes.  It works great, and I don't have to know exactly where my site is installed on the server.

So what is the best way to put up/take down the app_offline file?  If have seen some solutions where you rename an existing file ( app_offline.htm_ ) using an msbuild script.  But it seems like that would require me to know the location of this file.

Is there a way to do this through web_deploy?

Thanks

Comment: I found this article helpful: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/taking-web-applications-offline-with-web-deploy

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can enable AppOffline during a WebDeploy deployment you can even customize the AppOffline template:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:iisApp=sourceApp -dest:iisApp=destApp,appOfflineTemplate="offlineTemplate.htm" -enablerule:AppOffline
```

https://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/webdeploy-3-5-rtw

Comment: Keep in mind that the path specified in `appOfflineTemplate` is a path relative to the IIS website folder, and the file should already exist there.